# Reading GeoJSON keys and values from na Openlayers feature

Tags: django, openlayers, geojson

I'm using OpenLayers to create, display and edit features on the map. Features are saved as a JSONField in Django. Post Save I add a key django_pk to the JSON. How can I get this djanog_pk directly from the feature?

I need to do this so when the feature is edited, I know what feature to update in Django.

My JS code below:

```
<script>
      var raster = new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
      });

      var source = new ol.source.Vector({wrapX: false});

      var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: source
      });

      var format = new ol.format.GeoJSON();

      var select = new ol.interaction.Select({
        wrapX: false
      });

      var modify = new ol.interaction.Modify({
        features: select.getFeatures()
      });



      var map = new ol.Map({
        interactions: ol.interaction.defaults().extend([select, modify]),
        layers: [raster, vector],
        target: 'map',
        view: new ol.View({
          center: [-11000000, 4600000],
          zoom: 4
        })
      });

      var features = new ol.source.Vector({
          projection: 'EPSG:4326'
      });

      {% for polygon in polygons.0.gates %}
        console.log(format.readFeature({{ polygon|safe }}).getProperties()))
      {% endfor %}

      features.addFeature(format.readFeature({{ polygons.0.protected_area|safe }}));
      {% for polygon in polygons.0.gates %}
        features.addFeature(format.readFeature({{ polygon|safe }}));
        console.log(format.readFeature({{ polygon|safe }}))
      {% endfor %}

      var featureOverlay = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: features,
        style: new ol.style.Style({
          fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)'
          }),
          stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: '#ff78d1',
            width: 2
          }),
          image: new ol.style.Circle({
            radius: 6,
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
              color: '#4ca6b6'
            }),
          })
        })
      });
      featureOverlay.setMap(map);


</script>
```

I tried this: Buyt it only return geometry:

> select.on('select', function(e) {
>           console.log(e.selected[0].getProperties())
>         });

The JSONField in Django looks like this:

```
{
  "geometry":{
    "type":"Polygon",
    "coordinates":[
      [
        [
          -11156543.033928039,
          6698655.0485978
        ],
        [
          -11410925.464061106,
          5896371.999716589
        ],
        [
          -9972686.33984723,
          5084305.011214877
        ],
        [
          -9512841.177683609,
          6649735.350495286
        ],
        [
          -10090093.61529326,
          6972605.357971871
        ],
        [
          -11156543.033928039,
          6698655.0485978
        ]
      ]
    ]
  },
  "type":"Feature",
  "properties":null,
  "django_pk":10
}
```

So I need to find the django_pk for a feature when editing it, it selecting it, ot deleting it.

Not sure how to get this information

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I its actually simple.

You can read any property of the GeoJSON format:

```
select.on('select', function(e) {
   console.log(e.selected[0].getProperties())
});
```

Select being:

```
var select = new ol.interaction.Select({
        wrapX: false
      });
```

And in my Django code I just do this on post_save:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=ProtectedArea)
def update_json(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    post_save.disconnect(update_json, sender=ProtectedArea)
    try:
        instance.polygone = literal_eval("%s" % instance.geojson_file.read())
    except:
        pass

    if instance.polygone['properties'] == None:
        instance.polygone['properties'] = {}
        instance.polygone['properties']['pk'] = instance.pk
    else:   
        instance.polygone['properties']['pk'] = instance.pk
    instance.save()
    post_save.connect(update_json, sender=ProtectedArea)
```